# Batch for numbering lines in a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Guys I have two challenges:

1- It is creating a script to count lines in a text file. With that I developed the script below that does the right count and is working perfectly

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" myfile.txt | find /C ":""

for /f %%a in ('!cmd!') do set number=%%a
echo myfile.txt: %number% 
pause
```

2- It is to create a new column that number the lines of the file.

Example:
The file looks like this:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

It should look like this:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
```

does anyone know if it is possible to do this action in .bat?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "^" "c:\myfile"') do (
  (echo(%%b %%a)
)
```

?

Comment: Thank you!

that's what i need!

I just made a change to the code, so it could create a new text file with the change

thank you very much